# how do i make the website do something instead of refresh?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a todo app but when I press enter after I write something in the box, it doesn't add it to the list, instead, it refreshes the page.

I thought it has something to do with the `preventDefault()` part but I don't know.

Here is the code so far:

```js
const form = document.getElementById('form');
const input = document.getElementById('input');
const todos = document.getElementById('rodos');

form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const todoText = input.value;

    if(todoText) {
        const todoEl = document.createElement('li');
        todoEl.innerText = todoText;

        todoEl.addEventListener('click', () =>{
            todoEl.classList.toggle('completed');
        })

        todos.appendChild(todoEl);

        input.value = '';
    }
   
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel='stylesheet' href="style.css" />
        <script src='code.js'></script>
        <title>TODO List</title>
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Comfortaa:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>ToDo App</h1>
        <form id='form'>
            <input type='text' id="input" class="input" placeholder="What is your goal...?" autocomplete="off"/>
        <ul class="todos" id="todos">
            <li>Wake Up ;)</li>
        </ul>
        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: How are you submitting the form with no button?

Comment: could you clarify how would i go about adding a button to do that aswell as pressing enter?

Comment: Pressing enter makes the browser submit the form automatically. Just add an additional hidden input element so that browser wont submit the form

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in your js script, in line three:

`const todos = document.getElementById('rodos');`

should be:

`const todos = document.getElementById('todos');`

Also, move your `script` tag to the bottom, just before the `</body>`. If this script will be assigned before DOM loads, then it can't find any element, so it won't work.

There you have working snippet:

```js
const form = document.getElementById('form');
const input = document.getElementById('input');
const todos = document.getElementById('todos');

form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const todoText = input.value;

    if(todoText) {
        const todoEl = document.createElement('li');
        todoEl.innerText = todoText;

        todoEl.addEventListener('click', () =>{
            todoEl.classList.toggle('completed');
        })

        todos.appendChild(todoEl);

        input.value = '';
    }
    
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel='stylesheet' href="style.css" />
        <title>TODO List</title>
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Comfortaa:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>ToDo App</h1>
        <form id='form'>
            <input type='text' id="input" class="input" placeholder="What is your goal...?" autocomplete="off"/>
        <ul class="todos" id="todos">
            <li>Wake Up ;)</li>
        </ul>
        </form>
    <script src='code.js'></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: still doesnt work, but thank you never the less.

Comment: @AbdullahKhalil so, the main problem now is with page reloading?

Comment: the snippet works, maybe its the browser im using? cause it doesnt work from the files i have... Edit: its not the browser.

Comment: @AbdullahKhalil I've updated my answer, take a look :)

Comment: yess thank you so much it works now! :D i know this is good practice but now i think its a necessity. again, thank you so so much!

Comment: @AbdullahKhalil glad to hear that :) Happy learning!

Comment: Also, you can add `defer` to your script tag, which tells the browser to load the script only after the page gets loaded. `<script type='text/javascript' src='code.js' defer></script>` Now, you can place it anywhere.
P.s.: Adding `type` attribute is considered as a good practice.